# JQuery set correct tab active when closing new opend tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs

I have two tabs from which one you can open a new third tab and set this one active. When closing the new opened tab by clicking on the x icon the tab should be active from which one the new tab was opened. How can i set the correct tab active?

If user opens new tab from Tab1 and then closes the new tab (#3) then the active tab should again be tab1. If the user opens the new tab being on tab2 then the active tab shall be tab2 when he closes the new opened tab.

Here's my code to close the tab:

```
// close icon: removing the tab on click
tabs.delegate("span.ui-icon-close", "click", function () {
    var panelId = $(this).closest("li").remove().attr("aria-controls");
    $("#" + panelId).remove();
});
```

See my JSFiddle example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/metaxos/JvaRW/2/

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need someway to identify which tab proc'd the new tab. You can put a property on the tab 3 to designate which tab was used to open it.

```
addTab('tab-3', this.id); // this.id would be the id of the triggering tab

function addTab(newTabId, triggerId) {
     li = '<li><a href="#tabs-3">NEW TAB</a><span openerId='" + triggerId + "' class="ui-icon ui-icon-close" role="presentation">close</span></li>'
}
```

From inside your delete function, grab the id and use it to click the tab:

```
var theTab = $("#tab-3").attr('openerID');

$("#" + theTab).click();
```

Comment: Thank you. Could grab the openerId from the span but the $("#tabs-3").prop('openerId') brings 'undefined'. Also when setting the name the same on both. I've updated the JSFiddle: [link]http://jsfiddle.net/metaxos/JvaRW/6/

Comment: My bad. .prop won't return anything, as the value is an attribute of the element you create. Try using .attr (solution updated). Note, the id you'll get back will be the id of the link, not the id of the tab. You might need to do some parsing of the id to find the tab you. You'll also need to put ids on the tabs (li elements) in order to be able to select them via an id selector.